# Python check if variable is set or empty

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need check if input variable is set, I use python 3.5, example:

`./update-stack.py stack-name` (with stack-name as argument works)

instead

`./update-stack.py` (without stack-name i have an error)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update-stack.py", line 22, in <module>
    stack = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have write this for check this:

```
if len(sys.argv) <= 0:
    print('ERROR: you must specify the stack name')
    sys.exit(1)

stack = sys.argv[1]
```

How to see the `print` instead error?

Thanks

Comment: `try... except...`

Comment: Use `if len(sys.argv) <= 1:`.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to understand what `sys.argv` is first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.argv` has **at least** one element in it, `sys.argv[0]` is the script or module name (or `-c` when using that switch from the command line).

You need to test if you have fewer than 2 elements:

```
if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
```

or you could just catch the `IndexError` exception:

```
try:
    stack = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    print('ERROR: you must specify the stack name')
    sys.exit(1)
```

As a side note: I'd print error messages to `sys.stderr`:

```
print('ERROR: you must specify the stack name', file=sys.stderr)
```